# List with item titles and a dynamic url

Tags: web-part

I am using sharepoint 2013. I would like to use some OOTB webpart to show a list of items. The items are existing in list "Customers". This list has 1 column "Title". These list with titles needs to be hyperlinks with the following url:

```
http://myCompany.com/Lists/Catalogus/AllItems.aspx?[TITLE]
```

Example

```
http://myCompany.com/Lists/Catalogus/AllItems.aspx?Expertise=TestA
http://myCompany.com/Lists/Catalogus/AllItems.aspx?Expertise=TestB
http://myCompany.com/Lists/Catalogus/AllItems.aspx?Expertise=TestC
```

Which webpart can I implement this? Maybe CQWP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a calculated column in your Customers list with formula

=CONCATENATE("http://myCompany.com/Lists/Catalogus/AllItems.aspx?Expertise=",[Title])

and then use a list view web part which shows only this calculated column

Answer (score 2):

I think the old trick of the calculated column for emitting HTML could do in this case:

create a new calculated column of type Number with the following formula:

```
="<a href='" & "http://myCompany.com/Lists/Catalogus/AllItems.aspx?" & [Title] & "'>" & "http://myCompany.com/Lists/Catalogus/AllItems.aspx?" & [Title] & "</a>"
```